# receiving memory warning running TweetStation iPhone app on device - monotouch

Tags: iphone, memory-management, xamarin.ios

Since I couldn't make sense with why I receive so many memory warning (in Debug mode on iPod Touch) when I run my app on the device, I thought upload the TweetStation app (Debug mode again) instead as I was curious to see the results. To my surprise, the output was very similar in that a lot of memory warning were thrown and eventually it crashed! (see screenshot) Has it maybe nothing to do with my app whereas more to do with something completely different? Thanks for your help....

[image: Screenshot of Instruments output when running TweetStation app on my device in debug mode! Same results as my app]

Comment: what version of the iOS SDK and Xcode have you installed on your Mac ? version of MonoTouch, MonoDevelop and OSX would be useful too.

Comment: MonoDevelop 2.8.6.4, Monotouch 5.2.3, OSX 10.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Well, TweetStation does very little to release the memory it uses.   The only active memory disposal it performs is for images, but in general, it does not try to release any of the memory associated with any of the tweet display lists.

Comment: thanks, but does this mean that the above behaviour is to be expected on debug mode?

Comment: I would say: not only in debug mode. But more intensive in debug mode because of increased memory usage for debug builds.